# how do i apply opacity to a div wihout affecting the other elements within it?

Tags: css

Wen i apply opacity to a div, all the other elements within that div acquire the same opacity as the parent div, of which i want the children not to have any opacity. I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can only control the alpha of certain individual components of your parent `div` using the `rgba()` color notation. Even then, browser support for `rgba()` is slightly poorer than support for `opacity` and you can't use vendor extensions with it:

```css
#parent {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background-color: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

If you need browser support, use a transparent PNG image of the color instead:

```css
#parent {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background-image: url(bg.png);
}
```

Do not set the `opacity` property; otherwise the `opacity` of everything inside your parent `div` will be relative to this `opacity`, and specifying parent `opacity: 0.5` and child `opacity: 2.0` won't work either.

Comment: I would give this +1 if it included browser support :]

Comment: @Carrie Kendall: It was hinted at in the comment next to `background-color`, but I just expanded it into code anyway. Doesn't pay to be lazy ;)

Comment: You can set background color to grey using normal hexadecimal colors then set the rgba after, this will give a solid color for unsupported browsers.

Comment: @Luke Alderton: That too, but only if the intent is to fall back to an opaque color rather than transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: it's not possible. You need to restructure your markup.

EDIT - You want an explanation, you get it.

The [CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/PR-css3-color-20101028/#transparency) state

> <alphavalue>
>
> Syntactically a <number>. The uniform opacity setting to be applied **across an entire object**. Any values outside the range 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) will be clamped to this range. If the object is a container element, then the effect is as if the contents of the container element were blended against the current background using a mask where the value of each pixel of the mask is <alphavalue>. .

Which means that, well, the containers opacity applies to its contents.

Workarounds using `rgba` colors won't affect images, form elements, scroll bars etc.

I therefore suggest a restructuring of the markup like this:

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: .5">
        <!-- semi-transparent content here -->
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
        <!-- fully opaque content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm inclined to vote this down, but I'll leave it for now. What is your reasoning behind this? Did you read @BoltClock's post?

Comment: @Matti: Guess he meant it's not possible using the `opacity` property alone.